# How do I get a Dell Wireless 1350 adapter working?

Tags: wireless, dell, inspiron

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my dell inspiron 1150 that has a dell branded wireless adapter. It says firmware missing and does not allow me to use wifi. However I can connect with a ethernet connection. What should I do to get my dell wireless 1350 adapted to work with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

This is a quite common problem, first of all you should check that you've installed the restricted drivers for your wireless adapter. You can find these if you just search for "driver" in the Unity search bar. After installing these, you might get it to work.

If it still does not work, you might need to try other options. I would recommend you read the following:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide

Here's another link that I found by searching askubuntu for other questions regarding wireless connectivity on Dell laptops:

http://blog.tech4him.com/2011/09/broadcom-wireless-on-ubuntu-11-04-and-11-10/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Search in the ubuntu software center for "Installer package for firmware for the b43 driver" and install the package.
It works with my dell Latitude D 400 and 1350 wirelesscard.

Answer (score 0):

I did a standard install of 12.04 and am able to turn on the wireless by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd>, not <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> as you would do under Windows.